# Algebraic Proof of Stone-Weierstrass

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

I have seen a few proofs of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem today for the first time. While some were completely analytic, the proof given in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* hinted at an algebraic approach. He defines a sequence of normalized polynomials which he convolutes with the arbitrary continuous function $f(x)$ to obtain polynomial approximations. I am aware that convolution may be thought of as an inner product, hence was curious if there is a proof which uses algebraic language and minimizes the analysis.

Of course, I do not expect the analysis to disappear, but perhaps it can be marginalized. For example, while the easiest proofs of the fundamental theorem of algebra are entirely analytic, there are *mostly* algebraic proofs which only use analysis to assert that odd degree polynomials have a real root.

I seek such a proof because 1) I think it would be interesting, and 2) My intuition works best with algebra.

Comment: Note that convolution isn't an "inner product", since it's not scalar valued.  (The convolution of two functions is a function.)  Instead, it is the product operation for a [group algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_algebra)

Comment: That's fair. If we fix an $x_0$ at which to evaluate the convolution, then we get an inner product, no? Perhaps this is not a useful observation. I do not have enough experience to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm in $C(X)$ (the supremum norm) does not come from an inner product. More strongly, the topology in $C(X)$ is not induced by an inner product. The use of the convolution in Rudin's argument allows him to produce uniform approximations.

Finally, evaluation of the convolution at a point will produce a pre-inner product, but never an inner product.